# XlsxWriter exported file sometimes can't be opened by Numbers

Tags: python, django, numbers, libreoffice, xlsxwriter

This is a server rendered file, so it's saved to a Django HttpResponse with `{"in_memory": True}`

During QA testing, sometimes the file can't be opened by Numbers. It says

```
"calendar.xlsx" can't be opened right now.
The file format is invalid.
```

Yet it opens in LibreOffice just fine. No one here uses Windows so I haven't tested Excel yet. What info can I gleam from the file that will shed more info on this?

Comment: After inspecting the files and extracting them manually, this seems to be caused by `zipfile` on Mac vs Linux. I may be back with more info regarding OS compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZipFile` was indeed not the culprit. It turned out to be using the Django `HttpResponse` instance as the file-like object that the XlsxWriter `Workbook` would write to. It expects to be dealing with text, so it encodes everything. If you write the file first, then construct the `HttpResponse` with the final bytestring of the file, it'll be fine. This is true of any binary file.